# PHP imagecopyresampled fills whole destination image, but i need to fill only part

Tags: php

Source image width is 344 pixels and height is 86 pixels.

[image]

I create new blank image (destination) width 64 pixels and height also 64 pixels.
Then i want to resize source image, so that width is 64 pixels and height is proportionally less.

I did:

Get source image size.

```
$size = getimagesize( $_FILES['file_to_upload']['tmp_name'] );
```

Then set new width and height. Initial width is 344 pixels, i need 64, so new width is initial width divided with proportion (344 / 64). New height also is initial height divided with proportion.

```
$size[0] = $size[0]/($size[0]/64);
$size[1] = $size[1]/($size[0]/64);
```

Expecting that initial image resizes so that width will be 64 pixels and height 16 pixels.

Create initial image

```
$src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents( $_FILES['file_to_upload']['tmp_name'] ));
```

Create destination image

```
$dst = imagecreatetruecolor($width_64,$height_64);
```

Create necessary image

```
imagecopyresampled($dst,$src,0,0,0,0,$width_64,$height_64,$size[0],$size[1]);
imagepng($dst, $img_directory. '/pngicon64_64.png' );
```

But as result i get this

[image]

But i nee to get this

[image]

As understand code does not resample initial image. Just take part of it.
May be instead of `imagecopyresampled` need to use something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to calculate the image ratio, check which dimension is greater & reduce that one to your desired size, then calculate the smaller dimension using the image ratio.

An extremely similar example is available in the [PHP documenation for the imagecopyresampled function](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php#example-3562). I adapted that example to the code you provided:

```php
// The file
$filename = $_FILES['file_to_upload']['tmp_name'];

// Set a maximum height and width
$width = 64;
$height = 64;

// Get new dimensions
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($filename);

$ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
   $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
} else {
   $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
}

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

// Output
imagepng($image_p, $img_directory. '/pngicon64_64.png');
```